# Turn off file extension rename warning on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn off change file extension warning in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/67449/turn-off-change-file-extension-warning-in-windows-7)

I'm so tired of hitting the *Yes* button on a procedure that would be easily revertible if I made a mistake. I rename my file extensions frequently on purpose.

So, how do I disable the following warning on Windows XP SP3?

> Are you sure you want to change the file extension? This may … "

I've tried the suggestion in [Turn off change file extension warning in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/67449/turn-off-change-file-extension-warning-in-windows) but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe the magic number `#32770` is valid only in Windows 7?

Comment: @user1301428, doesnt seem to work. maybe the magic number #32770 is valid only in win7?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, that code should be the same for every version of Windows...