# Is there a way to modify the Windows 7 right click > New menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 - Add an item to ‘new’ context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/windows-7-add-an-item-to-new-context-menu)

I use OpenOffice.org, so the various OpenDocument files are available in the New menu, but I would like to make Office document formats available there as well. Is this possible?

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/34704/windows-7-add-an-item-to-new-context-menu

Comment: Hmm. I searched and that didn't come up (or I missed it). Thanks.

Comment: Happens to me all the time. I've had better luck doing a google search on superuser.com.