# Editing Registry to add NEW WORD 2010 option to right click menu

Tags: windows-registry

I would like to edit the "New" submenu that comes up when I right click within a folder. I know that to do that, I need to edit the registry with a ShellNew entry. I'm trying to add an option to open a New Word 2010 document but do not know the correct subfolder to add to the .docx menu.  I know for Word 2007 the folder is "Word.Document.12". What it is for 2010? I've tried "Word.Document.14" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/windows-7-add-an-item-to-new-context-menu)

Comment: Thanks for responding, but that doesn't tell me specifically what extension or folder name I need for Word 2010.

Example:

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docx\....?]

Right now the folder has:

\.docx\Word.Document.12\ShellNew

That creates a new 2007 word document. What do I need in the \.docx.... space to add a new Word 2010 document?

Comment: @Naomi You would make .docx be opened by word 2010 by default I guess.