# Windows 7 - add item to 'New' context menu

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 - Add an item to ‘new’ context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/windows-7-add-an-item-to-new-context-menu)

I've installed Access 2010 but have some software that can only handle the old .mdb files. When I right click an empty space in a folder and select 'New', I would like to create an .mdb file instead of .accdb.

I've managed to remove the "New Access Database" that created a new .accdb file, but I can't find how to create a context menu item to make a new .mdb file.

I've tried:

- [How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/windows-7-add-an-item-to-new-context-menu)
- http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/22001-new-context-menu-edit-desktop.html

However I've had no luck, nothing appears in the 'New' menu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a new ShellNew key under the file ending in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key of the registry. Inside that key, you then create a new REG_EXPAND_SZ entry and name it "ItemName", no quotes. For the value, enter the full path to the program that will open the new file, such as: "C:\Program Files\YourProgram\YourExecutable.exe",0

You do need the quotes this time because of the space in the path. The "0" that follows the path designates what icon in the executable will be used in the menu to represent the entry. If you don't know what icon number to use, simply try a few.

Then, create a REG_SZ entry named "NullFile" (no quotes) and leave the value blank.

> Always back up your registry by creating a restore point before making changes.

HINT: Take a look at the structure of some of the other file types that have entries in the New menu for tips on how to create your entry. The .txt entry is usually there unless removed.

Comment: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mdb\shellNew
I created String value NullFile (no value) and extended string Itemname = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE",0

Allso i tried creating the same string values in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mdb\Access.Application.14\shellNew

but still no "New Database" in context menu...

The hint: I exported everything from the .accdb to database.reg, edited all accdb to mdb and ran the database.reg with success

Comment: wonder why all by breaklines has been removed... Hope you can decipher the comment anyway :) thanks a million