# Windows Registry for New Menu with Batch Files

Tags: batch, windows-registry

[How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/windows-7-add-an-item-to-new-context-menu)

This shows how to add items to the "New" dropdown menu. How about taking them away?

Also, I want to make a batch file that automates this. Like this:

```
@echo off
echo Enter you file extension
set /p ext=
copy con ext.reg
echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 >> ext.reg
echo. >> ext.reg
echo [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.%ext%\ShellNew] >> ext.reg
echo "NullFile"="" >> ext.reg
start /wait ext.reg
del ext.reg
echo Complete
exit
```

1. Anything wrong with this, in general?
2. Can you write to other types of non-text files like registry files with batch files?
3. Please tell me the registry code for removing an item, so that I can add that.
4. Most importantly, can a registry file interact with the user, like take in input and make a variable so I don't need a batch file at all?

Answer (score 2):

1. I can't judge that, sorry.
2. I don't know of a good way to write binary (non-text) files from a batch script.
3. You can remove a registry key by using a `.reg` file as well. Simply by [placing a hyphen before the key](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516).

   > To delete a registry key with a .reg file, put a hyphen (-) in front of the RegistryPath in the .reg file. For example, to delete the Test subkey from the following registry key:
   >   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software`
   >   put a hyphen in front of the following registry key in the .reg file:
   >   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Test`
   >   The following example has a .reg file that can perform this task.
   >   `[`
   >   `-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Test`
   >   `]`
4. A registry file is only used to manipulate the registry hive. No user interaction (other than a confirmation prompt) is supported in the process to my knowledge.

Comment: how about the batch file? its the same idea, adding the delete

Answer (score 1):

1. Absolutely not, just be sure to back up the registry before you go hog wild.
2. Not very easily.  You'd be much better off simply writing a .reg file, which can handle just about everything you need.
3. In a .reg file, simply add a '-' (minus) after the opening bracket of the item to be removed.  See example below.
4. Nope.  Perhaps write a script (or batch file) to automate the generation of a .reg file, which can then be invoked.

Here are the contents of the registry file that I use to eliminate many of the common new template items in Windows 7.  Feel free to use it as a basis for your own.  **REMEMBER TO BACK UP THE REGISTRY FIRST**.

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
;Remove everything from the "New" menu other than folder and .txt

; MFC Trace file
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.trc\ShellNew]

;Briefcase
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Briefcase\ShellNew\Config]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Briefcase\ShellNew]

; Bitmap
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp\ShellNew]

; Contact
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.contact\ShellNew]

; Skype Contact
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.skype\Skype.Content\ShellNew]

; Link
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]

; Microsoft Word Documents
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.doc\Word.Document.8\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dochtml\wordhtmlfile\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docm\Word.DocumentMacroEnabled.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docx\Word.Document.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docxml\wordxmlfile\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dot\Word.Template.8\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dothtml\wordhtmltemplate\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dotm\Word.TemplateMacroEnabled.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dotx\Word.Template.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rtf\Word.RTF.8\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.wbk\Word.Backup.8\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.wiz\Word.Wizard.8\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.wll\Word.Addin.8\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rtf\ShellNew]

; Microsoft Excel Documents
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.csv\Excel.CSV\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.oft\Outlook.File.oft.14\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.slk\Excel.SLK\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xla\Excel.Addin\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlam\Excel.AddInMacroEnabled\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xld\Excel.Dialog\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlk\Excel.Backup\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xll\Excel.XLL\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlm\Excel.Macrosheet\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsb\Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlshtml\Excelhtmlfile\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsm\Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsx\Excel.Sheet.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlt\Excel.Template.8\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlthtml\Excelhtmltemplate\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xltm\Excel.TemplateMacroEnabled\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xltx\Excel.Template\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlw\Excel.Workspace\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xls\Excel.Sheet.8\ShellNew]

; Microsoft Powerpoint Documents
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pot\PowerPoint.Template.8\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pothtml\powerpointhtmltemplate\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.potm\PowerPoint.TemplateMacroEnabled.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.potx\PowerPoint.Template.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ppa\PowerPoint.Addin.8\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ppam\PowerPoint.Addin.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pps\PowerPoint.SlideShow.8\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ppsm\PowerPoint.SlideShowMacroEnabled.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ppsx\PowerPoint.SlideShow.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ppt\PowerPoint.Show.8\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ppthtml\powerpointhtmlfile\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pptm\PowerPoint.ShowMacroEnabled.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pptx\PowerPoint.Show.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pptxml\powerpointxmlfile\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pwz\PowerPoint.Wizard.8\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sldm\PowerPoint.SlideMacroEnabled.12\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sldx\PowerPoint.Slide.12\ShellNew]

; Microsoft Outlook entries
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.msg\Outlook.File.msg.14\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vcf\Outlook.File.vcf.14\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.hol\Outlook.File.hol.14\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ics\Outlook.File.ics.14\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pst\Outlook.File.pst.14\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vcs\Outlook.File.vcs.14\ShellNew]

; Microsoft Visio Drawing
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vdx\Visio.Drawing.11\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vsd\Visio.Drawing.11\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vss\Visio.Stencil.11\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vst\Visio.Template.11\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vsw\Visio.Workspace.11\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vsx\Visio.Stencil.11\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vtx\Visio.Template.11\ShellNew]

; Microsoft Project Document
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mpp\MSProject.Project.9\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mpt\MSProject.Template\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mpw\MSProject.Workspace\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mpx\MSProject.MPX\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mpd\MSProject.MPD\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mpf\MediaPackageFile\ShellNew]

; Microsoft OneNote
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.one\OneNote.Section.1\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.onepkg\OneNote.Package\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.onetoc\OneNote.TableOfContents\ShellNew]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.onetoc2\OneNote.TableOfContents.12\ShellNew]

; Microsoft Graph
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.gra\MSGraph.Chart.8\ShellNew]

; Microsoft Office Theme
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.thmx\OfficeTheme.12\ShellNew]

; Microsoft Office List Shortcut
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ols\OfficeListShortcut\ShellNew]

; Microsoft Journal Entry
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jnt\jntfile\ShellNew]

; Microsoft Publisher
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pub\Publisher.Document.14\ShellNew]

; PCB
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pcb\PCBFile\ShellNew]

; PDX
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdx\PDXFileType\ShellNew]

; UMP Profile
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.umprofile\umprofilefile\ShellNew]

; UMS Shortcut
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.umshortcut\umshortcutfile\ShellNew]

; Zip
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip\CompressedFolder\ShellNew]
```

Comment: I get the whole reg part, thanks. I just want to make it easier and interactive (for my family or something) with the batch file. How come I can't write to a reg file? I know it's binary, but isn't everything?

Comment: You can write a reg file.  You just can't write an interactive reg file.  They don't support any kind of user input.

Comment: so that batch file writing to the reg file part is good?

Comment: Yes.           ```````````

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line to get it working:

```
copy con ext.reg
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to why this would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

actually you **can** programmatically write/read/interact with the registry...

[usage, @ cmd] reg /?

to delete (via reg /? |clip :)

REG DELETE KeyName [/v ValueName | /ve | /va] [/f]

KeyName    [\Machine]FullKey
    Machine  Name of remote machine - omitting defaults to the current machine.
             Only HKLM and HKU are available on remote machines.
    FullKey  ROOTKEY\SubKey
    ROOTKEY  [ HKLM | HKCU | HKCR | HKU | HKCC ]
    SubKey   The full name of a registry key under the selected ROOTKEY.

ValueName  The value name, under the selected Key, to delete.
             When omitted, all subkeys and values under the Key are deleted.

/ve        delete the value of empty value name (Default).

/va        delete all values under this key.

/f         Forces the deletion without prompt.

Examples:

REG DELETE HKLM\Software\MyCo\MyApp\Timeout
    Deletes the registry key Timeout and its all subkeys and values

REG DELETE \ZODIAC\HKLM\Software\MyCo /v MTU
    Deletes the registry value MTU under MyCo on ZODIAC