# Edit file description shell new menu

Tags: windows, shell, windows-explorer, windows-registry, right-click

I've searched a lot but I cannot find a complete solution, I want to edit the file description in the explorer new file menu

now i have:
`Explorer right-click > New > Notepad++ Document` to create a new CSS file

That's not useful if I want to add one new file menu item for example a PHP file, which is registrated to be opened by Notepadd++. I suppose if I add one more menu item it would be also `Notepad++ Document`

I would like to change that to `new CSS file` and have the filename to be `style.css` if it's a CSS file, now its `New - Notepad++ Document.css`

Does anybody have an idea how to change that?

Comment: Try looking here  
  http://superuser.com/questions/34704/windows-7-add-an-item-to-new-context-menu  
and here  
  http://superuser.com/questions/400215/windows-explorer-context-menu-new-file

Comment: none of them answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/)

From the page:

> makes it easy to fix file association settings in Windows, including
>   context menu items, icons, and descriptions. Also: autoplay settings
>   and default programs settings ...all without fiddling around in the
>   registry.

Comment: great! exactly where I was looking for and even more! thanks a lot

Comment: The program **doesn't** allow editing the description of the file. It only promises it does, but really it edits the extensions' description. It was not significant in 2012, because THEN windows allowed us to edit the file description, but now it looks awful.