# How can I edit file description in Windows 11?

Tags: file-management, windows-11

The description can be seen in the hint of the file or in the second line of the General tab of the file properties.

[image]

The older versions of Windows allowed editing the file description. It was useful (as a hint). Now the field "description" is readable, contains useless information by default (such as the full name of the file), and I cannot find how it can be changed.

The Details panel simply does not show the description field.

Default Programs Editor (https://superuser.com/a/483349/134259) only promises it does, but really it edits the extensions' description. It is not the description of the specific file.

Comment: Even in Windows 10, I can't see any "description" field in Properties and in the columns list.

Comment: @harrymc The picture is added. It is Win 11.

Comment: This is then new to Windows 11 and you should remove your claim about "older Windows versions".  Have you tried to right-click the headers in Explorer and see if Description is available.

Comment: @harrymc the description field **does** exist in windows 10 - try checking the properties on a .bat file. The property is not editable in win10 though, just like the screenshot

Comment: @Gangnus some file types like Office docs have editable description fields under Properties > Details tab > Description > Title/Subject/etc. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Cpt.WhaleL You're right. I fired up a Windows 7 VM, and the Description field of a `.bat` file is also read-only and useless, so I think it was never user-updatable. Seems like an ancient option that was never fully implemented by Microsoft.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Maybe. I used that field for a long ago and it is very possible that it was done by some Office tool. I don't remember exactly. \*sigh\* Thank you, everybody, and let it be - it is not the worst error in the MS SW.