# "New Word Document" missing from right-click context menu?

Tags: microsoft-word, context-menu

When I right-click on an empty area of the desktop, I get a full context menu. Hovering over "New" brings up a new sub-context menu. "New Word Document" suddenly disappeared – it always used to be there!

So how can I put it back? This is on a Windows 7 system.

Comment: @greenber I'm sorry to hear it didn't help. about accepting answers have a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/184796 (has pictures).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Base on similar questions I checked, this might solve the issue:

> Click **Start** > **Run** > and type **winword.exe /r**

If this solution didn't work, you can have a look at [How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/windows-7-add-an-item-to-new-context-menu)

Comment: Worked for me too , thanks! (after doing so, all the window explorers screens should be closed and then after opening a new one again , it works).

Comment: nice it worked. although a little delay (about half a minute) after office repair finished and until word doc appeared in the "new" menu.

Comment: What about excel?

Comment: @HasanGürsoy maybe `excel.exe /r`, I'm not sure

Comment: Nope, It just opens excel.

Answer (score 7):

My situation was that I had both Office 2007 and Office 2010 installed on the same machine, via the drive image deployed to my work PC. Having both versions caused control struggles, with each version vying for control each time I launched it, so I opted to remove 2007. In so doing, the right-click "Create new" options disappeared.

I solved this by going to Control Panel → Programs and Features → Microsoft Office → Change → Repair.

Comment: This worked for me. On Windows 10, I was able to replace office 365 with office 2010 in the right click context menu. thanks !