# "Microsoft Office Word" option is gone from the create new menu

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“New Word Document” missing from right-click context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/439005/new-word-document-missing-from-right-click-context-menu)

I have Office 2007.
When I right click the folder screen of the "Windows Explorer" in order to create a new Microsoft Word document, it is not there:

[image]

It happened because I installed Open Office that replaced  all the Microsoft Office shortcuts in this screen with Open Office icons. Then I uninstalled Open Office and the Microsoft Word shortcut was gone.

How do I add it to the `Right Click > New` menu list?