# Windows context menu create new has RTF file but no DOC file

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, context-menu

When I right-click on an empty area of the desktop, I get a full context menu(windows 10). Hovering over "New" brings up a new sub-context menu.

I tried adding using this [Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/439005/new-word-document-missing-from-right-click-context-menu) but no help ... tried to fix Office through the control panel and still no help. I can create a RTF file but not a docx file.