# Adding custom new file like index.php and index.htm on ShellNew

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

This is related to
[How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/windows-7-add-an-item-to-new-context-menu)

But does anyone know how I can change the filename being used when I right-click a folder and select new?

I need it to be index.php instead of "New PHP File.php" that is being created by default.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/46952/138343) to that same question?

Comment: Yes, that partially works, I still need to change the filename to index.php