# Windows 7 user limitation

Tags: windows-7

I just installed Windows 7 pro x64 from Dreamspark (MSDNAA).
But i can't figure out how to configure it.

1/
When I want to acces some folders a pop up show up and tells me "that I need administrator acces to do it" I click the "continue" button and I can go inside the folder.
What was even the point in showing me this pop up? how can I remove it?

2/
In some folder when I do a right clic I can only create a new folder, not a new text file, not a rar, nothing.
In the same folder I also cannot extract RAR (by doing right clic, extract here)

Any Idea how to get back full control?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ You need to turn off UAC (User Account Control).
2/ There are restrictions what can be done in system and protected folders.
If you are administrator of this computer, turning off 1 will make effect for 2.

Answer (score 0):

1. Like pkobylin noted. That is UAC. The point is, the feature helps prevent malicious programs from performing administrative type tasks. If you'll notice the screen likely dimmed, the dialog window came into focus, etc. I don't believe that anything but the local mouse and keyboard can interact with that dialog window. I could be wrong though. Regardless, consider disabling it for the activities/programs that you frequent. Leave it turned on for others.
2. I suggest you read the following thread/link.

[superuser.com how can i add an item the new context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu)

Comment: Yeah don't worry i'm not a basic user. I did not reinstalled one of my system in years, last time I deactivated UAC it was on vista and you only had to deselect a checkbox.

Now you have a button to slide on 4 different preset, did not see that coming^^