# "Create new text document" option missing from context menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, context-menu

I noticed today that there is no longer a "Create new text document" option in my Windows 7 (x64 Ultimate) context menu when I right click. No idea how or when it disappeared, point is it's gone.

After searching Google for people with the same problem I tried following a post in [this guide](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/new-text-document-shortcut-missing-from-the-right/022309a6-cd08-41df-8e55-95e83397ae73).

But I got stuck right away because I don't see a `.txt` key in my registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. I only see a `.text` but I am not sure if that is the same thing.

Comment: Have a look a this post: http://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I gained access to another PC running Windows 7, a computer on which the context menu was intact. I peeked at the registry of this machine and copied exactly what was entered. Doing so resolved the problem on my desktop with the broken context menu.

Following all the instructions listed above, the two Strings within the `.txt` key that I needed were `Content Type` and `PerceivedType`.

So then to recap, if you are facing a similar issue, here is what I did to fix this problem. Hopefully it works for you as well.

(First backup the Registry.)

1. Open `regedit.exe`
2. Expand `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and look for a `.txt` key. If none exist, create one.
3. Within the `.txt` key, create two new Strings: `Content Type` and `PerceivedType`.
4. (Right click) **Modify...** and the value for `Default` should be `txtfile`.
5. (Right click) **Modify...** and the value for `Content Type` should be `text/plain`.
6. (Right click) **Modify...** and the value for `PerceivedType` should be `text`.
7. Create a new key with the name `ShellNew` within the `.txt` key.
8. Within the `ShellNew` key, create a new String with the name `NullFile`.
9. Within the `ShellNew` key, create a new **Expandable String Value** with the name `ItemName`.
10. (Right click) **Modify...** and the value for `ItemName` should be `@%SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe,-470`

Here are two screenshots of what the final outcome should be:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Diddnt really work for me, it seems that windows limits the number of entries on the context menu- I just removed some programs which had added context items and txt showed up.

Comment: To make it work i had to delete all other folders under .txt except ShellNew

Comment: it worked fine here, you just need to log off after making changes to the registry

Comment: Worked perfectly on Windows 10, without reboot, after deleting 5 unnecessary other context menu items.

Comment: Here, Notepad++ had seemingly changed the default value (at least its value was "Notepad++_file"). Changing it back to "txtfile" did the trick.

Comment: [Download ShellNewHandler from SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/shellnewhandler/files/latest/download) this works for me to easily untick what extra file formats i don't need, so that finally .txt is visible

Comment: For me it worked with just the description of Matt. Thanks for that. My problem was that i had a string value instead of an expandable string value.

Comment: I think my problem is too many other context menu items forcing out .txt
How to delete some of the others ?

Comment: Thanks @TillKolditz! In my case Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt (Default) was `txtfilelegacy`. Simply changed it to `txtfile` and restarted Windows Explorer and it worked.

Comment: I don't know how many hours I loss trying to do tutorials on the Web which they suggest to add "ShellNew" in the extension key and add NullFile as string and optionally FileName. This is working for a lot of extensions but NOT (*&@/@ Text files. Your solution is litterally a redemption for me. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 22):

Create a new file with the `.reg` extension, copy, paste, save and run.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; clear the key
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]

; and recreate
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
"PerceivedType"="text"
@="txtfile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
; @C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe,-470
"ItemName"=hex(2):40,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,\
  73,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,\
  00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,2d,00,34,00,\
  37,00,30,00,00,00
"NullFile"=""
```

Comment: Also, restart explorer afterwards (or just reboot)

Comment: Can you also mention how can I change the Label like instead of "New Text Document" add "New Text File" ?

Comment: @VickyDev no easy way, as expected of Windows, which in this case forces you to use only localized strings using its "MUI" technology, which stores everything in a binary format. After you compile the binary (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/creating-a-multilingual-user-interface-application), you have to replace the default value of "ItemName", which is "@%SYSTEM%\notepad.exe,-470",  to a reference to the compiled string using an "indirect string" pointer (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-registry-string-redirection).

Answer (score 8):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
"PerceivedType"="text"
@="txtfile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
"ItemName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,6e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
  2d,00,34,00,37,00,30,00,00,00
"NullFile"=""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile]
"EditFlags"=dword:00010000
@="Text Document"
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,\
  00,2c,00,2d,00,34,00,36,00,39,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,6d,00,\
  61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,31,\
  00,30,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,4f,00,\
  54,00,45,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,45,00,20,00,25,00,31,00,00,\
  00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,4f,00,\
  54,00,45,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,45,00,20,00,2f,00,70,00,20,\
  00,25,00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\printto]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\printto\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2f,00,70,00,74,\
  00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,32,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,\
  25,00,33,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,34,00,22,00,00,00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.txt]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.txt]
"PerceivedType"="document"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt\OpenWithList]
"a"="NOTEPAD.EXE"
"MRUList"="a"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt\OpenWithProgids]
"txtfile"=hex(0):
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: Worked for me on Win10, no restart needed.

Comment: Can you also mention how can I change the Label like instead of "New Text Document" add "New Text File" ?

Comment: This is the only solution that works.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft updates sometimes change permissions thereby killing acls for context features. After all these years it still happens to some of us.

- Go to `Desktop-> mouse 2 -> New`
- The populated Context Menu should be present.

If not, see earlier posts and check/fix the registry (great stuff!).
If yes, but not inside folders, then

- Go to `documents-> Mouse 2 -> New`
- If a folder is the only choice you get, then you've been excluded. To fix this make a "New Folder" in Documents, open it and then on a blank space inside that folder `Mouse 2 -> Properties-> Security` (Tab) `-> <user name> -> Permissions for <user name> -> Allow` (I recommend "Full Control" for yourself) `-> Apply`.

I didn't need to reboot.  I got this from a brainiac maniac in IT at work, hope this helps you too.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the .txt key yourself and then make sure that the following string value is there:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew\NullFile
```

The shell will use it to decide which items to put on the 'New' menu.

[image]

Microsoft has a KB article about it here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140333

If you're adding a brand new type (or fixing a broken one) you may need to add another entry to specify the text used. The default entry for the HKCR.txt should be 'txtfile'. Then make sure you have a HKCR\txtfile entry with default entry something like 'Text Document':

[image]

Close all instances of Explorer (ideally reboot) and that should work.

Comment: I tried all these suggestions and still no create new text document option. I even tried downloading a program mentioned in the other thread linked by Ganesh, the program called ShellNewHandeler. No .txt option in my context.

Comment: Updated to include information about the 'txtfile' entry.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, for some reason still no context menu entry for text documents. My registry editor screenshot looks identical to yours. Is it possible some sort of software is conflicting causing this?

Comment: Try creating a dummy key (e.g. for '.tst'). That's how I tested out these instructions. It didn't work for me until I created a tstfile entry and pointed the .tst default key to it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and even though all the registry keys appeared to be correct, the option for a new Text Document stubbornly refused to appear.

Only after *also* adding an empty text file named `empty.txt` to my machine's `\Windows\ShellNew` folder, did the option show up for me.  (The "empty" part of the name appears irrelevant -- Windows will look up the file type's friendly name in the registry.  But the extension matters.)

Don't ask me why/how/when the file disappeared...or became required, if it wasn't already there at some point. But that last step is what made things work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and look for a .txt in regedit.exe

2. Do export and (keep a copy as a backup) and copy paste the following code.

3. Finally import it as .txt . That's it. It works for me on Windows 10.

//credit goes to blackout1000
http://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/no-new-text-document-thru-right-mouse-click-menu-52234/

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
"Content Type"="text/plain"
@="txtfile"
"PerceivedType"="text"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\OpenWithList]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\shell\open\command]
@="notepad.exe %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
```

Comment: Can you also mention how can I change the Label like instead of "New Text Document" add "New Text File" ?

Answer (score 1):

(answer copied from https://www.tenforums.com/customization/184763-adding-notepad-right-click-new-menu.html)
Working for me with Notepad++

> if you just want to see an entry called "New" > "Notepad++ Document"
> in the context menu, then
>
> start Notepad++ as Admin, and then go to Settings > Preferences > File
> Association and then select Notepad under 'Supported extensions', pick
> .txt and press the Right hand arrow to transfer it under 'Registered
> extensions'.
>
> This will give you the context menu for New - Notepad++ Document. If
> you want to reverse the change, simply go through Notepad++ as Admin
> and move the .txt extension back to Notepad.

Comment: Nice one, this one fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Jan's answer is the most complete and accurate, however, as user Hightower mentioned, Windows limits the number of items that can appear in the "New" right click menu.

If you already have more than a few options...remove some that are already there. As soon as I removed the options for Word, Excel and Visio documents, sure enough, the Text Document option appeared.

Comment: How did you remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, but all the keys had their correct values. I just changed the value of ItemName to

```
C:\apps\Notepad++\notepad++.exe,-470
```

(That is, using the path where I have Notepad++ installed), and it worked. All my other entries are back in the "New" sub menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct version:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
@="txtfile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"
"PerceivedType"="text"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\OpenWithList]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\OpenWithList\notepad.exe]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
```

Comment: This is virtually a duplicate of Theva's answer.  The intention is that each answer provide a solution that is substantially different from what has already been contributed.

Answer (score 0):

i use windows10. i solved this way

1. Click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and look for a .txt in regedit.exe
2. Find .txt
3. New -> key. 
   key name is ShellEx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it happened after installing Notepad++. None of the mentioned solutions resolved this issue for me, however I was able to get it to work when I added the following to the Registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file]
@="Notepad++ Document"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file\DefaultIcon]
@="\"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file\shell\Edit]
@="&Edit"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file\shell\Edit\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\msohtmed.exe\" %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\OFFICE16\\MSOXMLED.EXE\" /verb open \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file\shell\Print]
@="&Print"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file\shell\Print\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\msohtmed.exe\" /p %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file\ShellEx\IconHandler]
@="{42042206-2D85-11D3-8CFF-005004838597}"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Removing Unwanted Context Items That Block New Text Document Entry

As explained in some of the other answers, Windows only allows a certain number of items in the right click `New` menu. So even if you have the `.txt` registry correct (as explained in the other answers), you may not see the `Text Document` entry in the `New` menu. Here's how to delete the extra entries.

1. Open Regedit.
2. Click the `File` -> `Export` -> `All`. Click `Save` to make a backup of your registry in case anything goes wrong.
   [image]
3. Navigate to Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   [image]
4. Press `CTRL-F` to Search and type in `ShellNew`.
   [image]
5. Press `F3` or Click `Find Next`.
6. When it stops on a "ShellNew" key, check the contents of the value `ItemName` (or it may be named `command` or `FileName`)

[image]

7. If the path shown is not for a file type you want in the context menu, delete the corresponding "ShellNew". Don't Delete any Keys which are not named simply "ShellNew".

[image]

8. Repeat 5-7 until you have deleted all the other unwanted ShellNew entries.
9. Check Your Context Menu To Verify .Txt Shows UP.
10. On Windows 10, you should be able to see the changes immediately, if not, try restarting the Windows shell using `Task Manager`:
    [image]
11. Test by right clicking in a folder you have permissions too (like the `Documents` folder). If you don't have permissions (e.g., in the root c:\ directory) you will see little if anything in the `New` menu.
    [image]

Answer (score -1):

My problem was that my "New → text file" didn't show up, but I had all the registers correct.

So I had to remove some programs from the list. Apparently Windows has a limit for how many programs to show there... I removed some Microsoft Office files I didn't use on a regular basis, and that worked for me.

Comment: Removed them how?