# Cannot create any new file when I right click in windows?

Tags: windows-7, right-click

Usually when I right click on my windows 7 pc I have the options to create a new file. Such as txt or bitmap or so. But now I do not have this option anymore. When I right click and select new I only have the option to create a new folder, but not a new file or anything else.

Is this a virus? Or what is wrong?

EDIT: I just saw that on my desktop it is possible, so there I have the options to create a new bitmap contact winrar excel sheet or whatever.

Comment: Have you installed any new software recently that could have change your Windows Shell file associations?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/629813/create-new-text-document-option-missing-from-context-menu

Comment: Might it be a permissions issue?  How many different locations have you tried it in?

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me as well. It seem Windows 7 (and later?) has some standard security feature which does not allow you to create a new file, except folders, on the system drive. If you create a new folder and enter the folder you should be able to create any files and folders you want.

So if you want to create files on the system drive without creating first a new folder you have to change the permissons on the c drive. One possible solution would be to take the ownwership. If its not abosutly necessary i would leave it as is.