# Can I add a "new -> blank document" option to the context menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows, context-menu

I was wondering if it was possible to add the option to create new documents **without extension** from the **context menu**.

This would enable me to create and structure my applications faster and more directly than every other alternative, such as:

- Have "hide knows file extensions..." permanently disabled; create new .txt file; change extension; accept Windows "changing an extension..." warning.
- Open text editor; write specific file; save as; navigate to directory, change extension, save.
- [Add a specific registry context menu entry](https://superuser.com/questions/629813/create-new-text-document-option-missing-from-context-menu) for **every** type of file.

Instead, I could just do:

- New blank file, add extension, repeat.

If it's of any importance, I'm coming from working mostly through Filezilla and its context menu works like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the link and description you have provided and use `..` instead of `.txt`.

I have

```
..
    (Default)    REG_SZ  NoExtensionFile
    ShellNew
        NullFile REG_SZ [empty]
NoExtensionFile
    (Default)      REG_SZ  File without extension
    Content Type   REG_SZ  text/plain
    PerceivedType  REG_SZ  text
```

[image: Screenshot]