# How to make "New" appear in the contextual menu when a file is selected?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu

When a file is selected in the Windows 7 Explorer, the contextual menu doesn't show the "New" element:

[image]

**How to force the "New" menu/submenu to appear even if a file is selected?**

This would make the solution from [How to create a new text document (TXT) file by a Hotkey?](https://superuser.com/questions/1091268/how-to-create-a-new-text-document-txt-file-by-a-hotkey) work even if a file has focus.

Comment: It's an interesting question. It is contrary to what a "context" menu does though. The context menu is displaying what you can do with the item you have selected. 'New' doesn't fit in to the context of a 'file.'  For that reason, I doubt this is possible. If it were, you would somehow have to modify the context menu of files and make options available based on the containing folder, and not the selected file object itself.

Comment: @Appleoddity Yes, I totally agree that it makes sense. But when you have an explorer window full of files, then you are always in a situation where a file has focus, and then the main solution from https://superuser.com/questions/1091268/how-to-create-a-new-text-document-txt-file-by-a-hotkey doesn't work. That's what I'm trying to fix :)

Comment: If you look into `HKCR\Folder` you see a `ShellNew` key. I found that if I duplicated this key under `HKCR\File` I got a `new` option in the context-menu of a file. But it only appears if I am right-clicking a file type that would normally appear in the 'new' context menu - such as a word document. When I click `new` I get a "new" duplicate of the file I right-clicked and it opens in word. So the secret is probably in there if it is possible at all. Will take some research and testing.

Comment: I take my previous comment back. The 'new' option appears to always be present on file types like Microsoft Office types. So, I'm not sure.