# “Create new text document” option missing from context menu

Tags: context-menu

The “Create new text document” option is missing from context menu, but only in certain folders: OS partition, Windows folder, Program Files, and probably other.
It is there if I create a folder in the OS partition.

This guide did not fix the issue:
["Create new text document" option missing from context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/629813/create-new-text-document-option-missing-from-context-menu)

How can it be added?
Win10x64 1909.

Comment: LE: apparently this is normal behavior.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal for Program Files. That is a secured folder and you cannot create a new Text Document there.

Make a folder C;\Temp, make sure Everyone has permissions, and then you can create a new Text Document there.