# Context menu for new file with template

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu

Is it possible to add a new entry in the context menu *New* which will generate a file based on a fixed template?

[image]

For example: I'd like to create a new html file where its content should be:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>New File</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- Body Contents -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](http://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu#46952)

Comment: @and31415 No, it is not duplicated. It asks for new approach. The creating of new file from predefined template.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, and31415's link should work as you'd expect. Based on linked answer:

Just open regedit and navigate to `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html\ShellNew]`. Create a new String Value named `FileName` (no spaces, note uppercase letters). Double-click it and give it a value: `html.html`.

[image: Edit String]

Next, open explorer, navigate to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Templates` and create a file called `html.html`. This is your template file where you can put the desired content to appear in each new html file that you create from context menu.

Comment: I have done what you regarded and I performed restarting Windows, but nothing I have got. This is a screen shot showing what I have done: http://postimg.org/image/v10zjlcm5/