# How can I add an item to the new-context-menu?

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

Because I'm new here I cannot add my question to [How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu), so I start a "new" question.

As Windows 10 admin I can change the registry to create a new HTML file from the new-context-menu in File Explorer (in the way described in the link above). I can also make a template HTML file. Both actions work like a charm, thank you all.

But, for security reasons, I usually work without admin rights (as standard user). As standard user I cannot update the registry and the updated admin registry is apparently not transferred to the standard users.

That is, a standard user does not see the new-context-menu with the option of creating a HTML file.

Does anybody know how to get out of this Catch-22 situation?

Comment: just do your admin stuff by logging into the admin account?

Answer (score 1):

I thought of an answer myself: as admin I give the standard user temporarily admin rights, sign in as this user, change the registry, sign in as admin again and change the rights of the user back to standard. This works.

By the way, a template file must be put into:
%appdata%\microsoft\windows\templates\{file.ext}