# Refresh user's template folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, templates

I have created new per-user file templates (not Office but plain text) for myself in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Templates` and I expected them to show up in Windows Explorer's context menu, under the *New* submenu. However, it's not there.

What did I do wrong or what did I miss doing?

I have also tried

- `C:\Windows\ShellNew` but it's only accessible for administrators, so that can't be the right place for per-user templates.
- `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates` (without *Windows*), but it didn't work either (and seems to be Office specific)
- `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Templates` but it's only accessible for administrators, so that can't be the right place for per-user templates.
- logging off and logging in again
- reading [How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](https://superuser.com/q/34704/105621) but all answers modify the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, which isn't a per-user setting. Doing the same in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\` is ok, but it removes the original template, which I don't want. Also, I didn't find a way of adding several templates for the same extension.