# How to add a custom file template to the right click --> "New" menu in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, context-menu, templates

I'd like to add a custom file template to my "New" menu when I right-click in Windows Explorer and go to "New." I want this custom template to simply be a LibreOffice Writer .odt document (as one of many examples of what I want) titled `my custom doc.odt` for instance. It will be formatted and configured according to my likings. In Linux (oddly enough), such as Xubuntu, this is trivial. You simply save any custom file template you want in the right-click menu into your user's `home/Templates` directory and it magically appears in the right-click menu. This is useful for a whole slew of custom-templated file-type, scripts, source code, or whatever--you get the idea.

How do I do this in Windows 8.1?

I've tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu), and other things, and spent many hours on this so far and nothing I do works. Please know that I am not looking for a LibreOffice-specific answer only, by the way, as I'd like a generic solution instead to cover any file type.

Note: I *am* open to "hack" type solutions too, such as writing a script file, available as a command in the right-click context menu, that simply copies a file from an arbitrary template folder into the current folder where I right-clicked. If you know how to do a work-around like this or something, that is perfectly fine too.

Comment: Can you post the file type association dump for .odt files? You can use [FileTypeDiag](http://www.pretentiousname.com/miscsoft/#FileTypeDiag) tool to generate the report.

Comment: I found some answers it looks like: https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu, and https://sourceforge.net/projects/shellnewhandler/, and http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-items-from-new-context-menu, and https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS602US602&q=edit+items+in+windows+new+context+menu&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikkN6B2LHWAhXBJCYKHVpUD-0QvwUIJSgA&biw=1280&bih=894

Comment: Also, side note: default templates for LibreOffice, as I discovered via my registry (run "regedit" then go to: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT --> .odt --> LibreOffice.WriterDocument.1 --> ShellNew --> see "FileName" field), are here: `C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\share\template\shellnew`