# "Create new file" entry at the root of the context menu

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu

Is there a way to create a "New file" entry at the root of the context menu (not in the *New* submenu)?

[image]

In other words, I need a command, which reproduces the `ShellNew` behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](http://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu)

Comment: @Ramhound "NOT in the New submenu"

Comment: Provide a screenshot of what you mean.  You said, "Is there a way to create a "New file" entry", which is what the duplicate answers.

Comment: I'm also not understanding what you want that's different.  Can you edit the question to clarify?  If people don't understand the difference, the question will attract the same answers.

Comment: @fixer1234 I just want to move the "New Text Document" entry from NewShell submenu to the root.

Comment: You can modify the context menu as you please. Just modify the registry. There are countless tutorials online on how to manipulate the explorer context menu