# Create a new "New" submenu in context menu with a custom name

Tags: windows, batch, windows-registry, context-menu

I like to experiment a lot with coding and creating html, css, js etc. files each time I want to try something is tiring. To get around this, I have created template html, css, etc. files and added them into "New" in context menu ([How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](https://superuser.com/a/46952/256296)).

Currently, I've added 4 items; html, css, js, and php. "New" submenu got a little crowded. Now I'm thinking if it's possible to create a new submenu with a custom name (e.g. "Coding") that I can add these files. Actual "New" submenu would be less crowded and I could access these coding files easily under a new submenu.

A second thought, this new submenu doesn't necessarily have to be just right in the context menu. It can be inside the "New" menu. I just want to group these four files.

Worst case scenario, can I reorder the "New" submenu? I'd like to stack these four at the top or at the bottom.

[image]

---

**Update:** I've created a [repository](https://github.com/akinuri/custom-context-submenu) for this functionality. Feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been searching for a solution to this, but the closest thing I came up with to what I want is adding a new item to the context menu which calls a script that makes a copy of a template file.

This isn't really what I want, but this might give someone an idea, so I'll post this anyway.

First, I searched for a way to add an item to the context menu. For example, Command Prompt. Following registry key does the job.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Directory\Background\shell => on empty space

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd]
"Icon"="cmd.exe,0"
@="Command Prompt"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe"

; Directory\shell => on a folder

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd]
@="Command Prompt"
"Icon"="cmd.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /k cd %1"
```

Next, I want to add an item that creates a file, e.g., a CSS file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\CSS]
@="Cascading Style Sheet Document"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\SysWow64\\SHELL32.dll,69"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\CSS\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\CustomNew\\css.bat"
```

Similar to Command Prompt registry key, this will add an item to the context-menu, but instead of running an application, it calls a bat file. Content of the bat file:

```
@echo off

copy C:\Windows\ShellNew\css.css %cd%

rename css.css "New Cascading Style Sheet Document.css"
```

I have a `css.css` template file in `C:\Windows\ShellNew`. I simply make a copy of the template file in the directory where I right click and choose `Cascading Style Sheet Document`.

[image]

Of course, I'll not use this method. This just complicates things even more. Imagine having all bat, css, html, js, and php files right in the context menu. I still need a better solution.

---

**Update:**

I may have found a solution. Original article: [Add Cascading Menus for Programs in Desktop and My Computer Context Menus in Windows 7 and Later - AskVG](http://www.askvg.com/add-cascading-menus-for-your-favorite-programs-in-windows-7-desktop-context-menu/)

Adding the custom menu to the context-menu:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Coding]
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\CustomNew\\coding.ico"
"MUIVerb"="Coding"
"SubCommands"="cmd;css;html;js;php;bat"
"Position"="Top"
```

For this menu to work, we need to define these commands `cmd`, `css`, `html`, etc. For example, defining the Command Prompt:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\cmd]
@="Command Prompt"
"Icon"="cmd.exe,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe"
```

Clicking on Command Prompt on the menu will run `cmd.exe`. This is straightforward. Tricky part is adding an item/app that creates a new file.

Let's start with a CSS file. Following registry will add the item to the menu.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\css]
@="Cascading Style Sheet Document"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\shell32.dll,-151"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\css\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\CustomNew\\css.bat"
```

While we have a new item with the name "Cascading Style Sheet Document", clicking on it, normally, wouldn't do anything. To make it create a new file in the current folder, we call a script.

I have prepared a batch script for each file type that I want to create; `bat.bat`, `css.bat`, `html.bat`, etc. and placed them in `C:\Windows\CustomNew`. Also I have placed the template files `bat.bat`, `css.css`, `html.html`, etc. in `C:\Windows\ShellNew`.

So whenever I click "Cascading Style Sheet Document" on the menu, I call the `css.bat` which makes a copy of the css template file and places it in the current folder.

`css.bat` file:

```
@echo off

copy C:\Windows\ShellNew\css.css "%cd%"

rename css.css "New Cascading Style Sheet Document.css"
```

It'd be better just to create a new css file without calling any script, but I don't think that's possible. However, if anyone has an any idea, I'd love to hear it.

Look at it. It's beautiful :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193852/how-can-i-add-item-in-desktop-menu-new-file-right-click-on-desktop)

To Add an Item in “New” menu:

- Type regedit in RUN dialog box and press Enter. Now expand
  “HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT” key.
- Now look for the file type which you want to add in “New” menu, e.g. for adding MP3 file type look for .MP3 key.
- Right-click on it and select “New -> Key” and give it name “ShellNew”.
- In right-side pane, right-click and select “New -> String Value”. Give it name “NullFile” and press Enter.
- Thats it. You’ll immediately get the file type entry in “New” menu.

Answer (score 0):

I created the attached reg file "template" that helps create a menu with two submenus in Windows 10.  I hope you find this useful.  Delete all the comments in the reg file after you complete your submenu.

```
;--------------------------------------------------

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;add.submenu.to.context.menu.blank.template
;(1) Change "MUIVerb"="MyNewMenu" to top level TITLE of both 
;Directory and Background menus (BOTH should have same TITLE)
;(2)Change all MyMenu1 to a unique identifier for this entire one submenu
;(3)Change "MUIVerb"="FirstCommand" to first command name
;(4)Change command line (@) following MUIVerb FirstCommand to desired first
command line
;(5)Change "MUIVerb"="SecondCommand" to second command name
;(7)Change command line (@) following MUIVerb SecondCommand to desired second
command line
;(8)Change icons if desired
;(9)Save file as .reg file

;This displays context menu when you right-click Directory
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\MyMenu1]
;Directory Level Menu Title 
"MUIVerb"="MyNewMenu"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MyMenu1"

;This displays context menu when you right-click Directory Background
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\MyMenu1]
;Background Level Menu Title
"MUIVerb"="MyNewMenu"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MyMenu1"

;First command under submenu
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MyMenu1\shell\open]
"MUIVerb"="FirstCommand"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MyMenu1\shell\open\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

;Second command under submenu
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MyMenu1\shell\runas]
"MUIVerb"="SecondCommand"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MyMenu1\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
;-------------------------------------------------
```