# How can I arrange the applications in right-click context menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Here's my right-click context menu:

[image]

I would like to know if I could just arrange them, with all the red line ones altogether with the others to be separated.

Comment: You should be able to sort the menu alphabetically or some other way. Right click on the menu and select Sort from the sub window that comes up.  That is the way it works on my own Windows 10 VM.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: [Order in the Windows Explorer context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7007852/1115360)?

Comment: @John, "Sort by' applies to items on the desktop, not items within the context menu.

Comment: You can create **cascading submenus**, which might help organize the context menus. See https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/creating-cascading-context-menus-with-the-windows-10-registry-f1cf3cd8398f ,  and https://superuser.com/questions/1242099/create-a-new-new-submenu-in-context-menu-with-a-custom-name , for example.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove items from the context menu, but you cannot change their
order, except via the "Sort by" sub-menu.

Wherever "Sort by" the "Date modified" is found, it might do what
you like, if these items were all added at the same time, but
might mess-up the order of other items.
In other contexts, other solutions/workarounds might be found.

Comment: "Sort by' applies to items on the *desktop*,  not items *within the context menu*.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: The poster's image is from the desktop, but I clarified my answer.