# Where is windows template folder for any file type?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I'm not talking about office template, I'm talking about template for any file type when you create a new one (when searching on Google I get only Word templates answer): if you put a file .ext in some special folder each time you create a new .ext file anywhere on File explorer it will copy that template.

I can't remember where the folder is located.

Comment: No, there is no such thing. Creating a file of a given type with a valid layout is the job of the software that deals with those file types, not the OS. if you create it manually it starts off 0 bytes long.

Comment: @FrankThomas yes there is because I used quite often when I was on Windows 7 :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but I landed on it before finding the real answer myself, so:

Unless I'm mistaken about what you meant the term you're looking for is "ShellNew" -- yes, two of the possible folders are named "Templates" but this makes it difficult to search for, as you've found out. :)

You'll want to head over to [How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu) and figure out which answer applies to you; What works will vary based on your Windows version.

Also, to address the mistaken comment on the question: It *IS* possible to specify a non-zero-byte template for Windows to use as a starting file; In fact, if I recall correctly this is exactly what MS Access used to do as a zero-byte file was not accepted as an Access database file. As noted in some of the answers, though, it is also possible to tell Windows "hey, a zero-byte file will do" via the NullFile setting. (Strangely, MS Word has enabled both a file template and NullFile, and [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/context#extending-the-new-submenu) makes it clear that NullFile takes precedence.)