# How can I reduce New item waiting time in Windows 10 Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, windows-explorer, context-menu

In Windows 10 Professional -> Right click -> New -> wait about 4-5 seconds on a fairly good laptop -> the list of items appear (New Folder, new shortcut etc.).

[image: New item]

This usually takes 1-2 seconds on other devices, so I am wondering what Windows is doing for generating this list and why it takes so long.

**Question:** How can I reduce New item waiting time in Windows 10 Explorer?

Comment: The right context menu should be shown instantaneously.  If you experience a 4-5 second delay you are either suffering from a failing storage device that is generating I/O errors or third-party software is causing the delay.

Comment: @Ramhound - the storage device seems to work fine (SSD) as I do not experience any I/O issues with anything else. It might be a third-party software though. Any suggestions about how to monitor what Windows is actually doing? (I see only CPU usage by explorer which would be the equivalent of intensive usage of a single core).

Comment: Do you have any software added menu items in the context menu? If so, one of them may be misbehaving,

Comment: Removing certain file types from that list might help. You can use this tool to do this: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_new.html (from: https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu)

Comment: I have not added any new item in the New item list. I have just used [ShellNewHandler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/shellnewhandler/) to remove some of them and it is still quite slow. Also tried Resource Monitor and there is increased disk read performed by Registry (image) during New (it is very slow, something like 20K/s). I guess somehow it wastes a lot of time reading the registry to compute that list.