# How can I add multiple templates for the same file type to the new context menu?

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

How would I achieve what is shown in the image below? Assume the first 3 items are text files each using different text file templates and the 4th item is one not using a template i.e. just a blank text file. Note that txt is only an example and I would like to expand this to other file extensions.

[image]

This problem was not solved by any of the answers in [How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu), so I made a new question as suggested.

A file (a.txt) was created and placed in C:\WINDOWS\SHELLNEW. Then the tests below were performed.

Using this code would result in creating a file with the .000 extension and not txt.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; new file type
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.000]
@="000"

; template
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.000\ShellNew]
"FileName"="a.txt"

; file type name
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\000]
@="Test"
```

Adding a FileName key to the .txt reg key only allowed 1 template to be used since it only allowed a path to 1 file.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
"FileName"="a.txt"
```

Using this code added a context menu item but it did not use the specified template and context menu name.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; new file type
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.000]
@="textfile"

; template
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.000\ShellNew]
"FileName"="a.txt"

; file type name
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\000]
@="Test"
```

Using this code would result in no context menu item to appear.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; new file type
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.000]
@="txt"

; template
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.000\ShellNew]
"FileName"="a.txt"

; file type name
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\000]
@="Test"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a way to do this which is the following. I assume that you want two templates for `.txt` files: one "default" template, and a second one which i'll call the "script template". I think that you can adapt to your own needs.

Write a `.reg` file containing (adapted from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1284919)):

```
; ------- .txt default ----------
; new file type
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
@="txt"

; template
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
"FileName"="C:\\Path\\to\\your\\template.txt"

; file type name
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txt]
@="Text File"

; ------- .txt script ----------
; new file type
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.script.txt]
@="script.txt"

; template
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.script.txt\ShellNew]
"FileName"="C:\\Path\\to\\your\\template_script.txt"

; file type name
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\script.txt]
@="Script text File"
```

Basically we create a fake extension `.script.txt` and a template for it.

The only drawback of this method is that your newly created script file will be named `New Script text File.script.txt`, with this extra `.script` that you might not want.
But since the extension ends with `.txt`, the files created that way will be opened with whatever program associated with the .txt extension.