# Add Extensionless file to the 'new' context menu?

Tags: windows, context-menu, right-click

When you right click in a folder you get an option to add a new file type such as .txt/.rtf
I want to add a file **without** extension to this menu.

How do i add an extensionless file to the (windows 10) 'new' context menu?

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu

Answer (score 0):

To create a default association for files with no extension,
create a `.reg` file containing text similar to the following
example, where `notepad` is defined as the handler:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\shell\openwithnotepad]
@="Open with Notepad"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\shell\openwithnotepad\command]
@="c:\\windows\\notepad.exe \"%1\""
```

Substitute in the above your program, instead of `notepad`,
then run the `.reg` file to enter this data into the registry
(administrator permissions required).

If you now double-click on a file with no extension,
it will open with your application.

Be careful to keep the `\"%1\"` parameter, and if the path to
your program contains blanks, then enclose the whole path in
quotes like this: `\"`.

Comment: I am trying to create the file from the windows right-click menu, not set a default program. I tried HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\ShellNew and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\ShellNew, but that didn't work